Bernoulli's Equation + Conservation of Mass
In the following example am I allowed to assume the velocity of point (1) is zero?

my argument for this is that since $D_{tank}>>D_{tube}$ therefore by writing the continuity equation or conservation of mass for this problem the flowrate must stay constant throughout the system and since $V_{tube}>>V_{tank}$ the velocity at the surface of the tank will be negligible, and because point (1) is within the tank its velocity also will be really small and therefore negligible compared to velocity accross the tube, but since point (1) is in vicinity of the tube I'm wondering if I'm making the right assumption or not? does the irrotationality of the flow required to use Bernoulli's equation justify my assumption?
any help would be appreciated and thank you.

For what purpose do you want to make the assumption

the problem wanted pressure at points 1,2, and 3 and flowrate of water that is being siphoned from the tank, so when I wrote Bernoull's equation between the surface of the tank and point 1 to find the pressure, that's where I made that assumption
